# Overflow SVG does not register clicks on OSX/iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, html, macos, svg

I have a small SVG canvas in my application which houses a button to click. Upon clicking that button, the small circle does some flashy work and opens up to an appropriate sized bubble to fit all the data. This data is just a list of data with custom bullets off to the left; some of this text is clickable (bound to click events) and causes other functions to be fired off. My problem is that the SVG canvas never changes in size. It's really only big enough to contain the original circle that the user clicks on. The rest of SVG elements that make up this control flow outside the bounds of the SVG canvas, but is all viewable due to the SVG having its overflow set to visible. Everything works fine in all browsers, but things change when I open up the application in an iPad or on a Mac (regardless of browser). It seems the overflow pieces of my SVG are completely invisible to the browser. Any click event that fires fine on the overflowed SVG elements on Window's browsers are completely invisible on OSX/iOS browsers (it seems like any click actually falls through to whatever is behind the overflowed SVG). At first I thought it was an issue with the click binding, but after searching and playing around with it, I think OSX/iOS just doesn't handle overflowed SVG very well.

To explain in its simplest form what's going on in my application, I have a very simple JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/yno8daka/

HTML:

```
  <svg style="overflow: visible !important" class="canvas" width='70px' height='70px' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
    <circle id="circle1" stroke="black" fill="black" stroke-width="1" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle2" stroke="black" fill="black" stroke-width="1" cx="110" cy="110" r="10"></circle>
  </svg>
```

Javascript:

```
  $('#circle1').click(function() {
    alert('yeah');
  })
  $('#circle2').click(function() {
    alert('yeah2');
  })
```

Circle1 is in the bounds of the SVG canvas, while circle2 is not. On Windows browsers, you will be able to click on both circles without any issue. On OSX/iOS browsers, the click event will fire for circle1, but not for circle2.
Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: Yes, [this was already pointed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891674/overflowing-svg-elements-in-some-versions-of-webkit-not-working-properly), it's more a browser engine issue, not an OS issue: it affects Safari and old Chrome versions that were using Webkit. Still no solution though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and link; I searched high and low and was unable to find anything on it. I was under the impression that it was the OS, as even the newest version of Chrome available for iOS has this issue, but it seems Chrome for OSX is working fine. The fact that the question you linked was asked 2.5 years ago, I have little faith in it being fixed any time soon. Shame.